# Need help using arraylists in program?

Tags: java

It seems that 20 regiments were in a continuous process of formation.  The first had 1000 men, the second had 950, the third 900, and so on down to the twentieth regiment, which garrisoned only 50.  During each week, 100 men were added to each regiment, and at week's end, the largest regiment was sent off to the front.This lasted for a total of 20 weeks.

For this program I have already managed to print out the original number of men for each regiment. But I am having difficult adding 100 men to each regiment.The adding men must be a method in the army class. I am getting the regiment objects using a .txt file. All this files contains is the names of regiments numbered 1-20.

```
public class Regiment {

    private String name;       //name of regiment 
    private int regNumber;     //regiment number
    private int men;           // regiment men 

    /**
     * Creates a Regiment object.
     *
     * @param regNumber the regiment number
     * @param name the name of the regiment
     * @param men the number of men in a regiment
     */
    public Regiment(int regNumber, String name, int men) {
        this.name = name;
        this.regNumber = regNumber;
        this.men = men;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the name of the regiment.
     *
     * @return the regiment name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of the regiment.
     *
     * @return regiment number
     */
    public int getregNumber() {

        return regNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of men in a regiment.
     *
     * @return men in regiment
     */
    public int getMen() {
        return men;
    }

    /**
     * Computes the number of men in a regiment
     */
    public int addMen2(int RegNumber) {

        int men = 1050 - (regNumber * 50);
        return men;

    }

}

class ArmyDataList {

    public ArrayList<Regiment> list;     // list of regiment objects

    /**
     * Creates an empty list
     */
    public ArmyDataList() {
        list = new ArrayList<Regiment>();
    }

    /**
     * Appends a regiment object to the list.
     *
     * @param current the object to be appended to the list
     */
    public void AddToList(Regiment current) {
        list.add(current);
    }

    /**
     * Removes a regiment object to the list.
     *
     * @param current the object to be removed from the list
     */
    public void RemoveFromList(Regiment current) {
        list.remove(current);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the largest regiment based on men.
     */
    public Regiment getLargest() {
        if (list.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        Regiment Reg1 = list.get(0);

        for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
            Regiment current = list.get(i);      // get next regiment
            // is current regiment > largest
            if (current.getMen() > Reg1.getMen()) {
                Reg1 = current;
            }
        }
        return Reg1;

    }

    /**
     * Adds men to each regiment.
     */
    public void addMen() {

    }

    /**
     * Converts the list to a multi-line string, with each line containing the
     * data for one regiment.
     *
     * @return the String containing all the data on the list
     */
    public String toString() {

        String out
                = String.format("%28s%12s%n", "Regiments", " Men")
                + String.format("%12s%n", "Number")
                + String.format("%12s%16s%14s%n", "=======", "===============",
                        "=========");

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

            Regiment regim = list.get(i);
            int regNumber = regim.getregNumber();
            String name = regim.getName();
            int men = regim.addMen2(regNumber);

            out = out + String.format("%12s", regNumber)
                    + String.format("%16s", name)
                    + String.format("%10s", men)
                    + "\n";
        }
        return out + "\n";

    }
}


 public class RegimentTest {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {


  ArmyDataList army = new ArmyDataList();

      // create Scanner object to read each line of file until eof
      Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File("regiments.txt"));

      System.out.println("Report Summary:\n");

      while (fileScan.hasNext()) // while not eof...
      {

         // read next line
         String line = fileScan.nextLine();

         // "echo print" data entered
         System.out.println(line);

         // 1. create a Scanner object
         Scanner in = new Scanner(line) ;

         // 2. extract tokens from current line
        int regNumber = in.nextInt();
        String name = in.next();
        int men = 0 ; //men is set to 0 only because I havent add the men yet


         // 3. create Regiment object passing the tokens to the constructor
        Regiment adder = new Regiment(regNumber, name, men );

         // 4. add object to list
         army.AddToList(adder) ;

      }


         System.out.println(army.toString());

      }
```

Comment: What is the problem? What are you having trouble with? What errors are you getting? Have you read the help section on how to ask a good question? Or do you just want someone to do your homework for you?

Comment: @MattCoubrough Yes, I want to do nothing but not to much :D

Comment: No. I do not get any errors I mentioned that the only problem was that I do not know how to add men to each regiment. All I would like is help understanding what I should do.

Comment: Any other help you can give me?

Answer (score 0):

You can write addNewMen() method in Regiment Class where you can add 100 more men as men is the property of regiment.

Comment: Thanks, will there be any way to do that in the army class.

Comment: No because it has regiment list as its variable.Men belong to regiment.